# How to edit a button element that was added as an appendChildElement(). and convert it to a font awesome icon

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The document was added as using javascript:

```
      const task_edit_el = document.createElement("button");
      task_edit_el.classList.add("edit");
      task_edit_el.innerHTML = "Edit";
```

Now this creates a button element with the inner html Edit. how do i change the inner html to a font awesome icon? since its not showing on the normal html page. it is manipulated to mount when a button is clicked.

Comment: This is answered in FontAwesome's documentation: [How To Add Icons](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/add-icons/how-to).

Comment: *"it is manipulated to mount when a button is clicked."* You need to bind an event handler to either the button or an ancestor of the button (recommended) in order to make that happen. Also, there's no such method called `.appendChildElement()` there's `.appendChild()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an "i" element inside in the button scope, after add class and finally add this i element to button element using add child.

```html
<button><i class="fa-thin fa-alarm-clock"></i> Alarm</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be an `<i>` element specifically, FontAwesome even suggests to [use `<span>` elements for accessibility reasons](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/add-icons/how-to#add-icons-to-html).